# Is Google open id (and other open id in general) subjected to change for the same user?

Tags: ruby, openid, omniauth

I recently encountered a situation where the same Google user visit my website twice but end up recognized as two different users. Although the email is the same, the openid is different.
Wonder if it just some kind of accident on my own (I'm using omniauth anyway)?
I have use Open ID in SO here for quite several years but never experience SO recognize me as someone else, so I guess Open ID should never change.
Is that true that Open ID of the same user can be changed?

Comment: Did anything at all change in your app? Especially URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's returned OpenID is a combination of the user's id and *your* domain. I.e. the user *foo@gmail.com* has a different OpenID when logging in at `example.com` and `bar.com`.